# How do I run a native code in corodova

Tags: objective-c, swift, cordova, cross-platform, phonegap-plugins

Is it possible that I can embed some native code with cordova ?

i.e In native application I can Intercept some javascript in webview  and run native code

Is it possible in corodova ?﻿

As far as I know it's not possible.Is there any plugin ? or something like that.

Comment: I think you just need to read cordova doc about plugins and you're good to go. Maybe you should delete your question, it is not really specific like most of the users like it (it is a risk to be marked down).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Please refer here 
http://docs.phonegap.com/tutorials/develop/1-embed-webview/ios/